# Swift Initializers

Tags: swift

The Swift documentation says,

> "You can override a failable initializer with a nonfailable initializer but not the other way around."

Can somebody explain why a nonfailable initialiser cannot be overriden by a failable initializer ?

Comment: May not be a standard stackoverflow question but it does have value so I don't get why so many downvotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A failable initializer returns an optional value. If you override that with a nonfailable initializer, you are returning a non-optional value and the compiler just wraps it in an optional. The other way around doesn't work. What is the compiler to do when your overriden initializer returns `nil`? How does it map that into an initializer that doesn't return an optional?

---

> I was under the impression that when you override a failable
>   initializer with a non failable initializer returned value is non
>   optional , So it didn't make any sense.

Well, it does return a non-optional if you call the `init` on the overriding class.  To see the optional return, you need to trick Swift into calling `init` on the base class.

How do you do that?  Here is a way:

```
class Foo {
    var x: Int

    required init?() {
        x = 4
    }
 }

class Bar : Foo {
     // required includes override automatically
     required init() {
        super.init()!
        x = 5
    }
 }

let bar1 = (Bar.self).init()    // this is equivalent to Bar()
let bar2 = (Bar.self as Foo.Type).init()
print(type(of: bar1))   // Bar
print(type(of: bar2))   // Optional<Foo>
print(type(of: bar2!))  // Bar
print(bar1.x)           // 5
print(bar2!.x)          // 5
```

**Notice:** `(Bar.self as Foo.Type).init()` returned an optional even though it was created with the non-failable `Bar` initializer.

**Note:** I had to add `required` to make this work, and `required` is an automatic `override`.  If you make `Foo`'s init non-failable and `Bar`'s init failable you will see the error message *Failable initializer 'init()' cannot override a non-failable initializer*

Comment: I was under the impression that when you override a failable initializer with a non failable initializer returned value is non optional  , So it didn't make any sense . Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: @rustylepord   But the doc syas "You can override a failable initializer with a nonfailable initializer", which means that still make sense?